# XSLT xsl:param looping - Return value if found within a text string

Tags: xml, xslt

**Objective**: Evaluate each `<Report_Entry>` element. Return the `<Internal_ID>` value if the `<External_ID>` value is contained anywhere within the `<Addenda>` text.

My current XSLT returns the desired output but I am looking for a more dynamic/scalable solution. My XSLT requires that I create 2 `xsl:param` statements for each `<Integration_Map_Value>`:

```
<xsl:param name="INT-MAP_External_ID_1" select="//Integration_Map_Value[1]/External_ID"/>

<xsl:param name="INT-MAP_Internal_ID_1" select="//Integration_Map_Value[1]/Internal_ID"/>
```

plus an `<xsl:when>` statement:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(upper-case(Addenda), $INT-MAP_External_ID_1)">
   <Internal_ID>
      <xsl:value-of select="$INT-MAP_Internal_ID_1"/>
   </Internal_ID>
</xsl:when>
```

**Issue:** Theoretically there could be an unlimited number of `<Integration_Map_Value>` instances so I am looking for a way of dynamically looping through all the `<External_ID>` values and comparing them against the `<Addenda>` field without having to create an endless amount of parameters, hardcoded instance numbers (i.e. [1]. [2], [3], etc.), and `<xsl:when>` statements.

**Source XML:**

```
<root>
    <Integration_Map_Data>
        <Integration_Map_Value>
            <External_ID>MICROSOFT 1234</External_ID>
            <Internal_ID>XYZ-001</Internal_ID>
        </Integration_Map_Value>
        <Integration_Map_Value>
            <External_ID>MEGACORP</External_ID>
            <Internal_ID>C10025</Internal_ID>
        </Integration_Map_Value>
        <Integration_Map_Value>
            <External_ID>WIDGET TOOLS, INC ABC</External_ID>
            <Internal_ID>C-000338</Internal_ID>
        </Integration_Map_Value>
    </Integration_Map_Data>
    <Report_Data>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Addenda>abc microsoft 1234567</Addenda>
            <OrderNo>4444</OrderNo>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Addenda>fubar MEGACORP LLC</Addenda>
            <OrderNo>5555</OrderNo>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <Addenda>no expected match here</Addenda>
            <OrderNo>6666</OrderNo>
        </Report_Entry>
    </Report_Data>
</root>
```

**Current XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- External ID Parameters -->
    <xsl:param name="INT-MAP_External_ID_1" select="//Integration_Map_Value[1]/External_ID"/>
    <xsl:param name="INT-MAP_External_ID_2" select="//Integration_Map_Value[2]/External_ID"/>
    <xsl:param name="INT-MAP_External_ID_3" select="//Integration_Map_Value[3]/External_ID"/>

    <!-- Internal ID Parameters -->
    <xsl:param name="INT-MAP_Internal_ID_1" select="//Integration_Map_Value[1]/Internal_ID"/>
    <xsl:param name="INT-MAP_Internal_ID_2" select="//Integration_Map_Value[2]/Internal_ID"/>
    <xsl:param name="INT-MAP_Internal_ID_3" select="//Integration_Map_Value[3]/Internal_ID"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/Report_Data/Report_Entry">
                <record>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Addenda"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="OrderNo"/>

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(upper-case(Addenda), $INT-MAP_External_ID_1)">
                            <Internal_ID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$INT-MAP_Internal_ID_1"/>
                            </Internal_ID>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(upper-case(Addenda), $INT-MAP_External_ID_2)">
                            <Internal_ID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$INT-MAP_Internal_ID_2"/>
                            </Internal_ID>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(upper-case(Addenda), $INT-MAP_External_ID_3)">
                            <Internal_ID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$INT-MAP_Internal_ID_3"/>
                            </Internal_ID>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <record>
      <Addenda>abc microsoft 1234567</Addenda>
      <OrderNo>4444</OrderNo>
      <Internal_ID>XYZ-001</Internal_ID>
   </record>
   <record>
      <Addenda>fubar MEGACORP LLC</Addenda>
      <OrderNo>5555</OrderNo>
      <Internal_ID>C10025</Internal_ID>
   </record>
   <record>
      <Addenda>no expected match here</Addenda>
      <OrderNo>6666</OrderNo>
   </record>
</root>
```

I’ve exhausted my beginner XSLT skills and can’t seem to figure out a more elegant solution to my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am open to using XSLT 3.0 but that is very new to me.

*Apologies for the title of this post... struggled to describe my issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple reference to the particular matching element e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
    <record>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), //Integration_Map_Value[contains(upper-case(current()/Addenda), External_ID)]/Internal_ID"/>
    </record>
  </xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation template plus

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Report_Data/Report_Entry"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

The identity transformation can be declared in XSLT 3 through `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, in earlier versions you have to spell it out as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, Martin!  It seems to be doing the correct lookup but the XML output contains just the values and not the actual element tags. For example, the <record> elements returns: 

<record> abc microsoft 1234567 4444 XYZ-001</record>

Rather than…

<record>
  <Addenda>abc microsoft 1234567</Addenda>
  <OrderNo>4444</OrderNo>
  <Internal_ID>XYZ-001</Internal_ID>
</record>

I must not have written your proposed XSLT correctly. Is there a way to preserve the XML elements?

Comment: @Jordan_ATX, I guess you didn't understand "plus the identity transformation template", see whether the edit helps.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! You are corect, I didn't pick up on your comment about the identity. This works perfectly. Thank you again!!!